# Android application to block all texts and calls but without disabling Internet (4G or WiFi)

Tags: android

I am looking for an Android application that can block/hide all texts and calls but without disabling Internet (4G/WiFi). Blocked texts and calls should be viewable once I re-enable the reception of texts and calls. Root required app is OK, free if possible.

Comment: Do you mean all incoming texts and calls, all outgoing texts and calls, or both?

Comment: Only incoming if possible

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: I use a Samsung Galaxy S3 with Android 4.1.2.

Comment: And what is the maximum amount of money you're prepared to pay? (I found a few apps, one of them paid, but it looks good)

Comment: Paid is OK too!

Comment: Have you tried [Focus Lock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.focuslock.zee)?

Comment: @VicAche Can you say the free apps to block text and calls ?

Comment: TomJ, I don't understand your question. I guess you could achieve call blocking with Focus Lock, but it's not what it is designed for, so I havn't made it an answer.